# Change Status Bar Color SwiftUI no UIHosting

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change my status bar color dynamically without success, anyone has any idea how to change it ?
I'm not using UIHosting controller so there is no AppDelegate or SceneDelegate fully using swiftUI:

```
@main
struct MyProjectApp: App{}
```

If i set `ZStack {}.preferredColorScheme(.light)` it only apply once, so if i go to another view and try to put `ZStack {}.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` it doesn't work.

I think i have try all the question here on stackoverflow, so if anyone have a definitive solution i appreciated.

@Updated code example

```
struct ContentA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentB()) {
                    Text("Show Detail View")
                }.navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
            }.preferredColorScheme(.light)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentB: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Hello ContetB")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

If you try to change StatusBar color using this way it doesn't work.

Comment: The `preferredColorScheme` changes color scheme of entire screen, not only status bar. Are you sure you want make it work?

Comment: @Asperi ok, this will be fine but it only works once...

Answer (score 0):

The colors within the app should be dynamic automatically, unless you set them specifically. You can toggle the .preferredColorScheme within the Previews section.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Comment: As i comment before, if i use preferredColorScheme(.dark) it only works once, if i have a second screen and put preferredColorScheme(.light) for example it will not work.

Comment: When running on a device, the entire app will be a single color scheme. I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: i update the main question, can you see if you have any idea how to solve this ?